# How I can replace page on on 'My product review' page on account side?

Tags: magento2

How can I edit this page as I want to change position of pager and  per page handler And want to place this before review div .
Image is : [image: My product review page]

Comment: you want per page handler above the reviews list ?

Comment: yes @ManojDeswal

Comment: does @Rakesh answer helped you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override file from `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/customer/list.phtml`

to your theme,

`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Review/templates/customer/list.phtml` file.

Clear cache.